# Doesn't display the image

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send an image to another view, but the problem is it doesn't display the image in the UIImage.
What I am doing is sending a String to the other view which if the string is the same as "one" or "two", etc. it is supposed to get the image from the assets.

```
if imagen=="one" {
    miImagen == UIImage(named: "one")
}
```

I check what I was sending and I print it (and it works). The only thing it doesn't display it.

```
import UIKit

class SecondController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var miImagen: UIImageView!

    var imagen = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if imagen=="uno" {
            self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "uno")
        }

        if imagen=="dos" {
             self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dos")
        }
        if imagen=="three" {
            self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "three")
        }
        if imagen=="four" {
            self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "four")
        }
        if imagen=="five" {
           self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "five")
        }
        if imagen=="six" {
             self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "six")
        }
        if imagen=="seven" {
             self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "seven")
        }
        if imagen=="eight" {
             self.miImagen.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "eight")
        }
    }
}
```

I added in one of my "ifs"  `print("Your image name is"+imagen")` and it works but it doesn't execute the other code.

Comment: Update your question with your code that actually attempts to display an image.

Comment: @rmaddy Done, its updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main issue is trying to use `==` instead of `=` to assign the image to the image view.

After that, there are several improvements you can make. Since `imagen` can only equal one value, you really should use `if else`.

```
if imagen == "uno" {
    miImagen.image = UIImage(named: "uno")
} else if imagen == "dos" {
        miImagen.image = UIImage(named: "dos")
} else if ... { // etc.
}
```

Better yet, use a `switch`:

```
switch imagen {
    case "uno":
        miImagen.image = UIImage(named: "uno")
    case "dos":
        miImagen.image = UIImage(named: "dos")
    // and the rest
    default:
        break
}
```

But the best solution is to take into account that the image you want is the same as the value for `imagen`. Replace your entire set of `if`s with just:

```
miImagen.image = UIImage(named: imagen)
```

That's all you need. Just one line will work for all of your images.